# Android how can i set numbers of a plain text digits after dot

Tags: java, android, digits, plaintext

i'm making a calculation of a formula. i wrote the codes and it worked but i want to see result of **velocity text** like this:

5.28 (**only 2 numbers after the dot**)
Digits Property of plaint text is not worked for me.
i stated velocity as double.

how can i do it ?

sorry for my poor English and Thank you.

edit:

```
    ...
    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    after some formulas
    velocity2 = velocity * 0.00508;
    drop2 = pressuredrop * 249.174;

    vel.setText(Double.toString(velocity2));
    dr.setText(Double.toString(drop2));
    }
```

now i must put your code into my codes but i don't know where :)
I'm sorry for this simple question. I really need to learn a lot of topics about java.

Comment: Where exactly do you need to see the text?

Comment: Have you written some code? Please edit your question and add the code (even if it is not working), so we can figure out where the bug is.

Comment: If you just want to print it with two decimal places (assuming you want it rounded). `System.out.printf ("%.2f" , num);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the decimal formatter for this as-

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");     
Log.d("formatted no is ",""+formatter.format(4.0));
```

**Edit**
You can modify your code like this-

```
 public void onButtonClick(View v)
    after some formulas
    velocity2 = velocity * 0.00508;
    drop2 = pressuredrop * 249.174;

    vel.setText(formatter.format(velocity2));
    dr.setText(formatter.format(drop2));
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i added my codes to question, could you please explain me to where i will add your codes ?